# How can I make postgres startup on connection - and shutdown after a period of being out of use?

Tags: linux, postgresql, systemd

In the day time I do software development where I use Postgres via Django on Ubuntu.

In the evening the computer is my personal laptop (still running Ubuntu).

How can I make Postgres startup when it receives a connection, and shut down if there is no activity for a while ?

I use systemd run services - so I imagine the startup part must be relatively straightforward ?

Comment: Development environments are off topic. I'd try to check if this is doable with inetd/xinetd though.

Comment: What do you want to save by doing so RAM or CPU? Cpu usage should be little unless the server has some task for self optimizing it's data (not sure if postgres has something like this). And RAM should be just a configuration option to minimize usage if the server is idle.